# Why does foreachPartition error out for streaming datasets?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am migrating from Spark Streaming to Structured Streaming and I am facing issue with the following code:

```scala
def processDataSet(inputDataset: Dataset[MyMessage], foobar: FooBar) = {
    inputDataset.foreachPartition { partitionIterator =>
      val filteredIterator = partitionIterator.filter(foobar.filter)
      ...
      ...
    }
}       
val streamingQuery = inputDataset
  .writeStream
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start
```

It errors out with the following `AnalysisException`:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;

Is `foreachPartition` not supported on streaming queries? Is `writeStream.foreach` the only way to implement `foreachPartition` in this case?

I'd like to avoid sending each event as it comes, but rather accumulate all rows, form one giant POST request body and send it to a HTTP endpoint. So if 1000 events in a batch and 5 partitions, generate 5 requests in parallel with 200 events in each request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes. `foreachPartition` action is not supported and you should use [ForeachWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter) instead.

Quoting the scaladoc of [foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@foreachPartition(f:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EUnit):Unit):

> **foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Applies a function `f` to each partition of this Dataset.

As you may have found out by now, `foreach` is an action and therefore triggers Spark execution.

Since you work with streaming Datasets, triggering their execution is not allowed using "traditional" methods like `foreach`.

Quoting Structured Streaming's [Unsupported Operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations):

> In addition, there are some Dataset methods that will not work on streaming Datasets. They are actions that will immediately run queries and return results, which does not make sense on a streaming Dataset. Rather, those functionalities can be done by explicitly starting a streaming query (see the next section regarding that).

Among the streaming alternatives is `foreach` operator (aka sink). That's how to do `foreachPartition` in Structured Streaming.

Quoting [Using Foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach):

> The foreach operation allows arbitrary operations to be computed on the output data.
>
> To use this, you will have to implement the interface `ForeachWriter`, which has methods that get called whenever there is a sequence of rows generated as output after a trigger.

---

> I'd like to avoid sending each event as it comes, but rather accumulate all rows, form one giant POST request body and send it to a HTTP endpoint. So if 1000 events in a batch and 5 partitions, generate 5 requests in parallel with 200 events in each request body.

That seems like an aggregation before writing the Dataset to a sink, doesn't it? Use `groupBy` operator and `collect_list` function to group rows so when you `writeStream` you'll have as many groups as you want.

I'd rather avoid dealing with this low-level feature of RDD called partitions as a way to optimize writes unless there is no other way.

Comment: I had a requirement to do this: foreachPartition( iterator -> collect everything for that partition from iterator in one go -> do something with it. Is there a way to collect all events for that partition?

Comment: I don't think the foreach sink allows for this --> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/ForeachSink.scala#L49-L64